# The usage of the word "clearly"!

Tags: usage, expressions

Can I say "good job. You describe the event very clearly"?
I am not sure I can use the word clearly like this. However, it sounds okay to me!

Thanks in advance

Comment: _Clearly_ is a fine choice. What makes you unsure about it?

Comment: I think Yael attempted (quite successfully if I may say) to translate a sentence from Hebrew to English. Anyway, Yael, it works just fine. Just one note, "you describe" is present simple, so if it's somebody who always or often describes events it's perfect. If he had described an event once then you should use "described".

Answer (score 0):

Well, each of those words seems appropriate *individually*, but not when assembled in that sentence.  The phrase "describe the event" seems a little odd to me -- yes, it is possible to describe an event, but (depending on the context) it might be more natural to ask someone to, "describe what happened."

Here are some examples where "clearly" sounds natural:

> Thanks for explaining the problem so clearly.
>
> Clearly he needs a haircut.
>
> The teacher clearly outlined what would be on the final exam.

Comment: I can't see a thing to object to in _"You describe the event very clearly."_